# adding and removing pseudo element with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I was tackling a challenge with signup form where I had to show custom error messages based on input validity-

[image]

Although I completed the challenge without `::after` element, it took me a whole day to find different ways to apply `::after` but at the end of the day, I decided to go the way I know and, leave it for another question on stackoverflow.

(From what I know) We can't add pseudo elements to input field with pure CSS. So I thought of adding it to field's parent Form-group. I found on searching through websites the `.after()` method but it adds child node, not `::after`. Moreover, it keeps on adding elements each time I hit submit.

Then I thought of  `let errorMessage = $("#"+field.parentNode+"::after");`, but even before I could do something like `errorMessage.css("content","Invalid message")`, it throws

`unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLDivElement]::after`

Now you know how screwed I was before deciding to go my simple way. Summed up everything, I just want to know the solution with `::after` if any! And also let me know if any of my above mentioned assumptions were wrong.
Here's my [solution](https://github.com/sapinder-pal/Intro-Component-with-Signup-Form) to this page.

Comment: I suggest inserting a properly styled div/span/p/whathever after input in the same container and change inner html to show what you need. After and Before elements can be tricky sometimes

Comment: @Tx_monster Though it's just been a month since I started in javascript, I don't know why I just want to know that trickier way, and know why I can't do this.